# How to create a super password with FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to find a way to add a super password to Symfony 2 with FosUserBundle.

By "Super Password" i mean you can take any username plus the password and you can log in using the standard log in form.

If you don't know excatly can you give me directions :

- Is it fosuserbundle which handle this part ?
- Is it the Security Bundle of Symfony 2 ?
- Which part do i need to override ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not exist and is probably not easy to accomplish. There is however the "switch user" functionality, which is very easy to enable in any Symfony application.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html